# Контейнер создается но не запускается докер (убунту)

Tags: python, ubuntu, docker

Я создал простенький образ пайтон приложения

```py
import calendar

print('Welcome to calendar')


year = int(input('Enter year'))
month = int(input('Enter number of month'))

print(calendar.month(year,month))
print('Good bye')
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

CMD [ "python","main.py" ]
```

После того как я успешно создал образ, запуская его контейнер создается, но не запускается.
В чем может быть причина?

(UPDATE)
сделал тоже самое только с винды Docker Desktop. Все заработало. Значит проблема в самом убунту на виртуалке.

Comment: Приведите код не картинкой а текстом.

Comment: вставил код текстом, спасибо за замечание, первый раз на стаке)

Comment: Я правил ваш вопрос так что код стал кодом а не просто текстом, примите мою правку.

Answer (score 0):

Что-то вы нам недоговариваете.

Я сделал контейнер по вашему примеру в Ubuntu 18, docker 20.10.20.

Создал каталог `~/tmp/try-docker`, в этом каталоге `Dockerfile` и `main.py`

```
$ ls ~/tmp/try-docker/
Dockerfile  main.py
```

Собрал контейнер

```
$ docker build -t try-docker .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.072kB
Step 1/4 : FROM python:alpine
 ---> 522335138ded
Step 2/4 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 16077e2171ed
Step 3/4 : COPY . .
 ---> 7eb20e588593
Step 4/4 : CMD [ "python","main.py" ]
 ---> Running in ced23c1be3c4
Removing intermediate container ced23c1be3c4
 ---> 567b4fd1d79d
Successfully built 567b4fd1d79d
Successfully tagged try-docker:latest
```

Запустил интерактивно с консолью

```
$ docker run --rm -it try-docker
Welcome to calendar
Enter year2003
Enter number of month12
   December 2003
Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7
 8  9 10 11 12 13 14
15 16 17 18 19 20 21
22 23 24 25 26 27 28
29 30 31

Good bye
```

Работает.

Покажите по шагам, как вы создаёте образ и запускаете контейнер.

Comment: Думаю у меня проблема с самим убунту. Попробывал еще на Centos, там тоже работает, удалил убунту попробую переустановить, спасибо )